# What is -XX , -X and -d in java? and what is -XX:+ means? what -XX:- means?

Tags: java

In java parameters(java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal) what is **-XX** means and **-d** means what. and something in -**XX:+** (with plus+) some things with (**XX:-**).

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

Comment: You might want to refer to the JVM vendo'rs doc. You're probably refering to the Oracle JVM so have a look there.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question.

Answer (score 2):

Those are [JVM options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html).

Please notice this question is receiving downvotes because it would have been as fast to check your favorite search engine to get an answer.

Comment: I had to put quotes around options `java "-X" "-D"` for google to find me this question.

Answer (score 0):

[DOC](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)

1. Boolean options are turned on with -XX:+ and turned off with
   -XX:-.
2. Numeric options are set with -XX:=. Numbers can include 'm' or 'M' for megabytes, 'k' or 'K' for kilobytes, and 'g' or 'G' for gigabytes (for example, 32k is the same as 32768).
3. String options are set with -XX:=, are usually used to specify a file, a path, or a list of commands
4. -Dname=value, -Dname:value, -Dname value